# T-SQL cast nesting

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to CAST the result of this back into an integer?

```
SELECT 
    CAST(7 AS DECIMAL (18,8)) * CAST(365 AS DECIMAL (18,8)) 
    / CAST(12 AS DECIMAL (18,8)) / CAST(7 AS DECIMAL (18,8))
```

The result was `30.416666`

But I want to CAST it back to a whole number i.e. `30`

I know it can be done by CASTING the whole lot but can't get the nesting right?

Comment: You said you want "30.416666" to be cast to an integer "39".....did you mean "30" or "31" rather than 39?

Comment: Perhaps you want [`Floor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx) or [`Round()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx). Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. (`SELECT cast( CAST(7 AS DECIMAL (18,8)) * CAST(365 AS DECIMAL (18,8)) / CAST(12 AS DECIMAL (18,8)) / CAST(7 AS DECIMAL (18,8)) as Int)` is too easy.)

Comment: Parentheses are your friends. Embrace and use.

Comment: Also note that casting to an int is the same as using floor(), which simply truncates. As previously mentioned it depends on whether 30.6 should become 30 or 31.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to cast the final result to INT

```
SELECT cast(CAST(7 AS DECIMAL(18, 8)) * CAST(365 AS DECIMAL(18, 8)) 
    / CAST(12 AS DECIMAL(18, 8)) / CAST(7 AS DECIMAL(18, 8)) AS INT)
```

Comment: Controlling *when* the rounding/truncation happens would be a valid reason for making everything a decimal and then cleaning up at the end, especially if dealing with financial calculations.